Rotation along Cartesian coordinates in terms of $\theta$ and $\phi$ of spherical coordinates
Suppose we have the following cartesian and spherical coordinates.

And the rotation matrices $(R_x,R_y,R_z)$ along three cartesian coordinates follows the right hand rotation rule as following:

Now imagine that we have a vector $\vec v$ which is initially parallel to the z-axis. We want to rotate this $\vec v$ vector such that it becomes parallel to the vector $\vec r$ given in above the picture (i.e., it makes angle $\theta$ with z-axis and angle $\phi$ with x-axis). How can we do this rotation in terms of rotation matrices? Can we do this by following:
$$
\vec r = [R_z(\phi) R_y(\theta)] \vec s
$$
or by
$$
\vec r = [R_z(\phi) R_x(\theta)] \vec s
$$

Visually, it it clear to make $\vec{v}$ parallel to $\hat{r}$ we should first rotate about the $\hat{z}$ axis by angle $\varphi$, then about the rotated $\hat{y}$ axis by angle $\theta$. By the rotated $\hat{y}$ axis, I mean the new $\hat{y}$ axis which results from first rotating the coordinate system through by angle $\varphi$ about $\hat{z}$. This process is described by the product of rotation matrices
$$
R_{y'}(\theta)\,R_{z}(\varphi)\tag{1}
$$
where $R_{y'}(\theta)$ describes rotation about the rotated $\hat{y}$ axis. It can be related to rotations in the original coordinate system by
$$
R_{y'}(\theta)=R_{z}(\varphi)R_{y}(\theta)R_{z}^{-1}(\varphi)
\tag{2}
$$
Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$, the sequence of coordinate transformations we should apply is
$$
R_{z}(\varphi)R_{y}(\theta)
$$
which agrees with your first guess (assuming $\phi$ in your notation is $\varphi$ in the diagram).
Source: J.J. Sakurai and Jim Napolitano, Modern Quantum Mechanics, 3e.
EDIT: As Kurt G. noted in the comments, there are more than one possible combinations of rotation matrices to map $\vec{v}$ into a vector parallel with $\hat{r}$. Here is a more computational approach to the problem. Following the convention on Wikipedia, define the three rotation matrices about the Cartesian axes as:
$$
\begin{align*}
R_x(\theta)
&=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\
0&\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\\[0.3em]
R_y(\theta)
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&0&\sin\theta\\
0&1&0\\
-\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\\[0.3em]
R_z(\theta)
&=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
$$
where $\theta$ here is a dummy variable; i.e. it is not necessarily the spherical angle $\theta$. In the basis of Cartesian unit vectors, we describe $\vec{v}$ by
$$
\vec{v}=C\langle0,0,1\rangle^T
$$
where $C>0$ is an arbitrary multiplicative constant, and we describe $\hat{r}$ by
$$
\hat{r}=\langle \sin\theta\cos\varphi,\sin\theta\sin\varphi,\cos\theta\rangle^T
$$
Then you can show that both matrix-vector products
$$
\begin{align*}
&R_z(\varphi)\,R_y(\theta)\,\vec{v}\\
&R_z(\varphi+\pi/2)\,R_x(\theta)\,\vec{v}\\
\end{align*}
$$
will produce a vector parallel to $\vec{v}$. Perhaps there are other combinations of rotation matrices that will produce the same  effect?

I'll update my answer to account for the multiple possibilities, but should it be $R_z(\pi/2+\phi)$? If I rotate first about $\hat{x}$, then the tip of $\vec{s}$ will hover over the negative $y$-axis. I then have to rotate by $\pi/2+\phi$  to make $\vec{s},\hat{r}$ parallel.
